# Multiple Parametered URL CORS error

Tags: javascript, ajax, tomcat, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have to hit a url say `http://localhostName:8080/TestModule?paramA=3432&paramB=0.` My code is not working for URL with multiple parameters, however it is working perfectly fine for a single parameter say `'http://localhostName:8080/TestModule?paramA=3432.` Can someone please tell me some reason why this could be happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I am doing an xhr call with following CORS enabled call.

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}
```

Also I have added following filters in my web.xml of tomcat, and have also added the required cors-filter-2.1 jar and java-property-utils-1.7.1.jar in the lib of tomcat.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Should make zero difference. Is that the actual values in the querystring?

Comment: No, the actual values are a bit different, but the format is the same. paramA and paramB are functionId and functionType respectively and localhostName is localhost. If i hit the sample URL in the browser with two parameters, it works fine. It shows the response. But only in FireFox it throws the CORS error only when accessed through xhr call.

Answer (score -1):

It was nothing but a wrong URL issue, added / after TestModule and it started working. :) `http://localhostName:8080/TestModule/?paramA=3432`